# Changing Title attributes of a bunch of music files by a script

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, batch-rename

I have quite a lot of music files but their title attributes have the track numbers infront of them, like 01.TrackName, 02.TrackName.
What is the best way to strip off integers from the file attributes?

Edit: I am using windows and all music files are MP3. Any solution as batch files, c++ or .net etc will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this has a better life on SuperUser? It's not strictly and purely programming-related, especially when looking at the answers so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use Flexible File Renamer to rename the files per your needs. It does require some familiarity with patterns and, in some advanced scenarios, regular expressions.

There are several other similar tools on the market, each with their own scope as to what they can do and how easily it can be done.

See http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA014830/english/FlexRena/.  The website shows a screenshot of a user batch-renaming a set of MP3 files using not only elements within the filename but also ID3 tag-related information such as track title and artist.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Flash Renamer](http://www.rlvision.com/flashren/about.asp)  Great util, and it has support for renameing MP3's

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ID3 tag editor. Some have support for batch tagging using regexes. Another option would be to use python with the id3 tag library (I don't remember its name...)

**Edit:** For example http://www.mp3tag.de/en/

[Mutagen](http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/wiki/Development/Mutagen): Id3 tag library for python.

Answer (score 0):

Select all your mp3 files (there may be thousands) with the Tag and Rename program and export them as export.xlsx. When you open this file with Excel, you can perform any operation you can think of. With this method, you can adjust 10 thousand files as you wish within 1 hour. Do not change column headings and locations while in Excel. When you first extract the export.xlsx file, be sure to make a backup of it.